# Rankin-Selberg convolution and product of degrees as of Christmas 2019

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

Almost 5 years ago (time flies), I asked in [Rankin-Selberg convolution and product of degrees](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194770/rankin-selberg-convolution-and-product-of-degrees?r=SearchResults) whether the Rankin-Selberg convolution of two automorphic representations of respectively $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ and
$\operatorname{GL}_{n'}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ gave rise to an automorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}_{n.n'}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. Paul Garrett answered it by giving the known cases where this was proven at that time.

Have there been breakthroughs so far getting us any closer to such a general result?

Edit August 12th 2022: what about now? I would be especially interested in the case where the degree of the Rankin-Selberg convolution L-function is a prime power, that is $d_{F^{\otimes k}}=(d_{F})^{k}$ with $d_{F}\in\mathbb{P}$. A proof of this equality would entail that the following weakening of Goldbach's conjecture: "every composite even integer is the sum of 2 prime powers" implies that an L-function of composite even degree is a twist of a non primitive L-function.

Comment: I don't think so.  It's a hard problem.

Comment: I think the general solution of this problem lies a few dozen Fields medals away at least, to paraphrase Jack Schwartz's famous remark about artificial intelligence. (This would also apply to the prime-power-degree special case you're hoping for, which doesn't actually seem to have any reason to be easier than the general case.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Newton and Thorne](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11261) proved that if $\pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ corresponding with a holomorphic cuspidal newform of even integral weight $k\geq 2$, squarefree level, and trivial central character, then for each $n\geq 1$, the $n$-th symmetric power lift $\mathrm{Sym}^n \pi$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$.  We have the standard identity

$\mathrm{Sym}^n \pi\otimes\mathrm{Sym}^n\pi = \boxplus_{j=0}^n \mathrm{Sym}^{2j}\pi$,

so by Newton--Thorne, this is an isobaric automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_{(n+1)^2}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$.  This is not yet known to hold for $\pi$ corresponding with Hecke--Maass forms.  Thus this is a thin set of examples, but I find it noteworthy nonetheless.  This showed up on the arxiv the day before you posted your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Are there known important properties, even conjectural, that are stable under RS convolution ?